# Odd RuntimeException when using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

My code is as follows:

```
private void startRecording() {
            try {

                mFileName = getActivity().getDir("testDir", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
                mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, mFileName);
                //FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(mFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
                mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch(RuntimeException re){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "runtime exception" + re.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            mRecorder.start();
        }
```

When I try and run the application on the emulator (or on my phone) the app crashes and I get the following LogCat log:

```
03-05 12:14:46.770: I/AudioRecordTest(5035): /data/data/com.example.test/app_testDir/audiorecordtest.3gp
03-05 12:14:46.890: E/MediaRecorder(5035): start failed: -2147483648
03-05 12:14:46.890: D/AndroidRuntime(5035): Shutting down VM
03-05 12:14:46.900: W/dalvikvm(5035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a2aba8)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035): Process: com.example.test, PID: 5035
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$RecordPlayFragment.startRecording(MainActivity.java:331)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$RecordPlayFragment.onRecord(MainActivity.java:277)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$RecordPlayFragment.access$0(MainActivity.java:275)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$RecordPlayFragment$RecordButton$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:345)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-05 12:14:46.960: E/AndroidRuntime(5035):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am just wondering if anybody knows what is going on here since after googling I havn't found anything that looks like the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the file is being created on a folder where you have the permissions to write?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure I can. Just did some quick tests to verify `File testFile = new File(getActivity().getDir("testDir", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath());
              Log.i("LOG_TAG", "testFile can write: " + testFile.canWrite());
              Log.i("LOG_TAG", "testFile path: " + testFile.getAbsolutePath());`  Also this directory should just be the app's data directory, so I should be able to access and write to it.

Comment: Did you add `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yup, all the permissions are there.

Comment: what if you put `mRecorder.start();` in the try block to see if it catches something there! Unfortunately `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.` isnt very helpful :/

Comment: Catching the .start() doesn't really add anything to the debugging unfortunately.  I am in the process of just rewriting the code to see if I just missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Added in:

```
File tempFile = new File(mFileName);
```

And changed the mediaRecorder.setOutputFile to:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());
```

Not even sure why it wouldnt work with the file streams, but it works this way.